# How to dynamically recalculate height of new rows in nested grid with css grid system and tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, css-grid

I used css grid to align my content as shown in the image.
The problem is, the height of the second row header, holds the same height of the previous row, which adds extra unneeded white space for the header (header 3), description3 and footer3.

Is there a way to dynamically refresh/recalculate the height of that second row ?
And I used grid because I want text on the same row to be aligned horizontally
[image]

```
import "./tailwind.css";

const items = [
  {
    header:
      "I am a very large header one I am a very large header one I am a very large header one",
    description: "This is a very large description for the header number one",
    footer: "footer one"
  },
  {
    header: "I am a  header 2",
    description: "This is description 2",
    footer: "footer 2"
  },
  {
    header: "header 3",
    description: "Description 3",
    footer: "footer 3"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="m-12 grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-2 gap-4">
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="grid grid-rows-3 border-black border-4" key={index}>
            <p className="border-2">{item.header}</p>
            <p className="border-2">{item.description}</p>
            <p>{item.footer}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer to that.

Comment: grid align your content,why you want second row calc it's height?I think they are in conflict.

Comment: @Mee I know, but I'm explicitly telling the parent grid to have 2 rows, so it should calculate the height of each (parent) row individually , shouldn't  it?

Comment: Remove `grid-rows-2` - that should be enough. You may also look at `auto-rows-` [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-rows)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka that's it,also i think the point is sub container, maybe should remove `grid-rows-3` on sub.

Comment: Thanks @Mee and @IharAliakseyenka, this is exactly what I wanted. 

Now I noticed the `footer one` is getting the same height of `header 1` I assume this is because I use grid-rows-3 in the child wrapper. When I try to use auto-rows- the alignment of rows disappears!

Comment: Here's a sandbox that illustrates it https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-breeze-6ghw0i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: no , i can not get it work,maybe try table?